# Tensorflow: nan during matrix multiplication and addition

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, nan

I'm using a function (ndegree_poly) which gets a tensor and an array of weights, and calculates the result of a polynomial from them.

The code seems straight forward enough, but when the degree increases, or the function is repeated multiple times, the resulting tensor contains a bunch of nans and infs. The infs are reasonable. But if the numbers are getting really small, shouldn't they become zero, instead of nan?

```
import tensorflow as tf

function_degree = 10

def ndegree_poly(x, a, degree=6):
        op = tf.add_n([tf.multiply(tf.pow(x, i), a[i]) for i in range(1, degree)])
        return tf.add(op, a[0])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    poly_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([function_freedom, 1, 5]))

    mat = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 5]))

    result0 = ndegree_poly(mat, poly_weight, function_degree)
    result1 = ndegree_poly(result0, poly_weight, function_degree)
    result2 = ndegree_poly(result1, poly_weight, function_degree)
    result3 = ndegree_poly(result2, poly_weight, function_degree)
    result4 = ndegree_poly(result3, poly_weight, function_degree)


    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(result4))
```

it prints:

```
[[-0.28569764         nan         nan         nan        -inf]
 [        nan         nan  3.55561209         nan  0.53827095]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nan` values do not come from very small coefficients, it's just the "natural" result of trying to do ∞ - ∞, as the coefficients come from a normal distribution and so are both positive and negative.

```
import math
import tensorflow as tf

tf_inf = tf.constant(inf)
res = tf_inf - tf_inf
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(res))

>>> nan
```